# returning the least cost!

Tags: java

Hi
I have written such a code below but it returns wrong output which is not the least value.

```
    private Element heuristic_Function(List<Element> objectList) {
    System.out.println(objectList.toString());
    Element node =objectList.get(objectList.size() - 1);
    double leastValue = objectList.get(0).getGreedy();
    System.out.println(leastValue);

    for (Element e : objectList) {


        if (leastValue > e.getGreedy()) {


            leastValue = e.getGreedy();
            node = e;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(node.toString());
    System.out.println(leastValue);
    return node;
}
```

I send a list to this method several times but it will return wrong output.

output:

```
[digit:1  greedy2.87 , digit:2 greedy3.67 ,digit:3 greedy3.24 , digit:4  greedy3.67 ] //System.out.println(objectList.toString());
2.87  //System.out.println(leastValue);
digit:4 greedy3.67  //System.out.println(node.toString());
2.87  //System.out.println(leastValue);


[digit:1 greedy2.87 , digit:2  greedy3.67 , digit:3 greedy3.24  , digit:1 greedy3.67 , digit:2  greedy4.47 , digit:3 greedy4.3500000000000005 ] //  System.out.println(objectList.toString());

2.87  //System.out.println(leastValue);
digit:3  greedy4.3500000000000005 //System.out.println(node.toString());
2.87   //System.out.println(leastValue);
```

MY question is: why it doesn't return the node which has the least greedy (least value)?
thanks

Comment: My guess is that your getGreedy method is borked.

Comment: public void setGreedy(double greedy) {
        this.greedy = greedy;
    }

Comment: the code above is my getGreedy() method which is ok

Comment: @user472221: How can your getGreedy method be called setGreedy?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on the Code Review site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the initialisation function to `Element node =objectList.get(0);`
as shown here

```
 private Element heuristic_Function(List<Element> objectList) {
    System.out.println(objectList.toString());
    Element node =objectList.get(0); // REPLACE WITH THIS
    double leastValue = objectList.get(0).getGreedy();
    System.out.println(leastValue);

    for (Element e : objectList) {


        if (leastValue > e.getGreedy()) {


            leastValue = e.getGreedy();
            node = e;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(node.toString());
    System.out.println(leastValue);
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Your problem was that you initialized leastValue to the value from the first node, but node to the last node. So if the first node has the smallest value, the greater than test is never true, and you never update node, thus leaving it pointing to the wrong node.